# $|G-H|<\infty$ so $|G|<\infty$

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ is a group and $H<G$ such that $|G-H|<\infty$. Prove that $|G|<\infty$.

Truthfully, there is a hint for it:

> $H$ cannot be an infinite subgroup.

It is clear if $|H|<\infty$, since $|G-H|<\infty$ then $|G|<\infty$ and problem will be solved. But cannot understand why "$H$ cannot be an infinite subgroup". Thanks for your help.

Comment: Look at the size of the cosets of $H$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We assume that $H\neq G$ (otherwise take $G$ infinite to get a counter-example). Let $x_0\in G\setminus H$. Then $x_0 H\cap H=\emptyset $ as $H$ is a subgroup, and since $|G\setminus H|$ is finite, so is $x_0 H$ (as the map $a\mapsto x_0 a$ is a bijection). We deduce that $H$ is finite.

Comment: why "and so is $x_0H$" ? can you please explain ?

Comment: @Belgi There is a bijection between the elements of $H$ and the elements of $x_0H$ given by $x\rightarrow x_0x$.

Comment: @Belgi I've added the detail.

Comment: backslash is for the quotient or $-$ (minus) of sets ?

Comment: In the initial version of the question, $H$ was a subgroup (not necessarily normal) hence it's the minus of sets.

Comment: I think the last part is confusing. The fact that $x_0H$ is finite follows from the fact that is a subset of a finite set; the bijection allows you to infer that $H$ is then finite.

Comment: I would suggest the following, which I believe is clearer: "[...], so is $x_0H$. As the map $a\mapsto x_0a$ is a bijection, we deduce that H is also finite."

Comment: In fact,when $H$ is infinite so $gh$, $h\in H, g\in G-H$ cannot belong to $H$. A contradiction!. Thanks Davide for your time. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Either $|G-H|= 0$  or there exists an element $g \in G-H$. In the first case it is clear that $G=H$ and this would allow $G$ to be infinite.
And in the second:
Suppose H was not finite. Then $gH\cap H = \{1\}$ and hence $gH-\{1\} \subseteq G-H$ would be infinite contrary to your assumption. Hence $H$ is finite.

With $H$ being finite and $G-H$ being finite we can conclude that $G$ is also finite.

Comment: At the first line, you shoul write $g\in G\setminus H$. Why would $1$ be in $gH$?